How reasonable is it to divide an offset by an integer to make the model non-singular?
I have been trying to fit a GLMM (Poisson) into a dataset which has flock size as response variable, climatic data as fixed effects, and different Zoos in the USA as random effects. I am a novice in the field of regression modeling, and I tried different methods by reading some resources and asking questions in the public forums. But I am highly confused!!!
Based on some expert suggestions, I used the following model:
glmer(Flock_size ~ scaled(Climate data) + (1 | Zoo) + offset (a column with flock sizes of previous years),  data = d, family = poisson)[![enter image description here][1]][1]


Where offset = log of the flock sizes of previous years
It resulted in singular fit.
The qqplot is as follows:

The observed and the expected values are largely non-aligned.

Now, what I did is that I chose to divide the offset by an arbitrary value of 100 to see what difference does it make
glmer(Flock_size ~ scaled(Climate data) + (1 | Zoo) + offset (column with flock sizes of previous years/100),  data = d, family = poisson)
It resulted in a non-singular model with an improved qqplot as follows:

I would like to know how reasonable is it to divide an offset by an intiger to make the model non-singular ?
Thanks

what happens if you use the log of the pervious year's flock size? Since you are using a Poisson GLM, I assume that your software is automatically using an exponential link, such that as you are presently modeling it, you are accidentally saying that the expected flock size is $e^P$, where $P$ is previous year's size. Dividing by 100 doesn't make any sense, but it accidentally gets us closer to the logarithm.

I used the log actually, and resulted in singular fit. When I divided it by 100 [log(flock size)/100] and used it as offset. Model became non-singular and qqplot improved.

That probably approximates the effect of removing the offset, since you've massively shrunk its additive term to 0.

The use of the offset is completely wrong. The offset functions like a variable for which no coefficient is estimated as it is equal to one by definition. It is a repeated measures design, in that the size of each flock is measured over time. In such cases, it is ideal to include a random slope and model the autocorrelation at the flock level using perhaps an autoregressive (AR1) model.
